# Set field to not update to database

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Is it possible to set a field so that it get not saved/stored in DB?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "quota")
    private int quota;
...
}
```

If the value is changed it should not be saved/stored in the database. But I dont want to make it @Transient cause the value is stored in the db.

Is this possible with an Annotation? Or do I have to check the value before saving?

Thanks

Comment: you can commit the transaction then change its value, it will not be saved in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `updatable`:

```
@Column(name = "quota", updatable = false)
private int quota;
```

[Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Column.html#updatable--):

> (Optional) Whether the column is included in SQL UPDATE statements
>   generated by the persistence provider.